# Prevent multiple instances of Service

Tags: android, android-service

I'm running an `Android Service` which is run every 3 seconds.

Many times, the working within the `Service` class is unable to complete in 3 seconds, but a new instance is launched anyways. 
I want to avoid multiple instances. How can I do this?

My code is as follows:

```
public void task() {
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startConnection();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```

I can think of a couple of way to deal with this:

1. Is there a way I can check if an instance is already running? If yes, then I can skip the loop.
2. Is there any inbuilt functionality to prevent running multiple instances?
3. Another option is to set & reset a flag & check flag status.

May be there are better ways to do this?
What is the best approach?

Thanks

Comment: a `Service` is a singleton: you cannot have multiple instances of the same `Service`

Comment: Adding to pskink comment, you should add timer into service itself, to do task every 3 sec/min, instead-of starting service many times.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html). From the page:

> All requests are handled on a single worker thread -- they may take as long as necessary (and will not block the application's main loop), but only one request will be processed at a time.

An IntentService a little like this will "expire" after SERVICE_EXPIRE_TIME_MILLIS has passed, and skip to the next request. (Thought it might be useful for your particular example).

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {

    private static final String ACTION_FOO = "bubblebearapps.co.uk.scratchpad.action.FOO";

    // TODO: Rename parameters
    private static final String EXTRA_PAREM_TTL = "bubblebearapps.co.uk.scratchpad.extra.TTL";

    private static final long SERVICE_EXPIRE_TIME_MILLIS = 3000;

    /**
     * Starts this service to perform action Foo with the given parameters. If
     * the service is already performing a task this action will be queued.
     *
     * @see IntentService
     */
    // TODO: Customize helper method
    public static void startActionFoo(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyIntentService.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_FOO);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PAREM_TTL, System.currentTimeMillis() + SERVICE_EXPIRE_TIME_MILLIS);
        context.startService(intent);
    }

    public MyIntentService() {
        super("MyIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (ACTION_FOO.equals(action)) {
                final long param1 = intent.getLongExtra(EXTRA_PAREM_TTL, 0);
                handleActionFoo(param1);
            }
        }
    }

    private void handleActionFoo(long expiryTime) {

        if(System.currentTimeMillis() > expiryTime){
            //skip work and return
        }

    }
}
```